# windows task schedule to open a web page - vbs not working

Tags: vbscript

hopefully this will be an easy one? I've got a VBS file which I am trying to schedule every week to do a XML refresh. It simply calls an ASPX page. But I cannot get the thing to work! Even when I try to double click the VBS file I just get an error message. The actual code can be found all over the place - it seems to be standard code for this purpose.

The code is (fetch.vbs)

```
Call LogEntry()

Sub LogEntry()

        'Force the script to finish on an error.
        On Error Resume Next

        'Declare variables
        Dim objRequest
        Dim URL

        Set objRequest = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")

        'Put together the URL link appending the Variables.
        URL = "http://mywebsite/fetchXML.aspx"

        'Open the HTTP request and pass the URL to the objRequest object
        objRequest.open "POST", URL , false

        'Send the HTML Request
        objRequest.Send

        'Set the object to nothing
        Set objRequest = Nothing

End Sub
```

The error message I get from windows (when I double click the VBS file is)

```
Script: fetch.vbs
Line: 1
Char: 1
Error: Invalid Character
Code: 800A0408
Source: Microsoft VBScript Compilation Error
```

Any ideas?!

Comment: sorted... it was because I hadn't saved it as ANSI (answer from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039104/vbscript-invalid-character-800a0408-compilation-error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was solved by saving as ANSI format (not UTF-8 as default)
ref: [VBScript Invalid Character 800A0408 compilation error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039104/vbscript-invalid-character-800a0408-compilation-error)

Comment: if you solved the problem you should mark this as the answer, even if you answered it yourself :)

Answer (score 0):

it looks like it may be the encoding. especially for line 1 char 1.